# Is there a way to easily import around 600-700gbs of json into ElasticSearch with node?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I've been trying to search for this but I can't seem to find a solution that will work around memory constraints and OOM, I'm currently working on a search engine for my job and as part of it we want to have a cred stuffing search engine for Purple team engagements.

The json is formatted as so,

```
[{
"email": "bob@bob.com",
"password": "123",
}]
```

We have about 600-700gb of records we want to import into the ElasticSearch, I've tried splitting the data up and doing a loop over it in node but I keep running into resource issues.

Comment: Split the data into smaller chunks.  After processing a chunk, make sure all references to that chunk are nulled or out of scope (and thus eligible for garbage collection.  If that, by itself, isn't enough, then pause with a `setTimeout()` for a couple seconds between chunks to give the garbage collector some time to run.  If that's not enough, then add a call to `global.gc()` (with associated command line argument to enable it).  If that's not enough, then we need to see your actual code that implements the last option.

Comment: Does it need to be with node or you can use other tool? Filebeat and Logstash will do that easily.

Answer (score -1):

awk 'NR >= startlinenumber && NR <= endlinenumber' /path/to/file

inside an exec, and then increment startline/endline in a loop. You can either do this loop in a bash script and then simply call your node js script and read from stdin.